# What is the divergence in retarded Bondi coordinates?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, metric-spaces, tensors, curvilinear-coordinates

What is the divergence operator $\nabla$ in retarded Bondi coordinates in Minkowski spacetime?

$(t,r, \theta, \phi) \rightarrow (u, r, \theta, \phi)$ with $u=t-r$

The line element is $ds^2 = g^M_{\mu \nu} dx^{\mu}dx^{\nu} = dt^2 -dr^2 -r^2 (d\theta^2 +sin^2\theta d\varphi^2)$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Have you tried to use the formula from [the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence#In_curvilinear_coordinates)?

Comment: $$\nabla_\mu T^\mu=\frac{1}{\sqrt g}\,\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}\left(\sqrt g\, T^\mu\right)$$